# Clone Azure Media Services asset/video using AMS v3

Tags: .net, azure, video-streaming, video-processing, azure-media-services

What's the best approach to cloning video assets in Azure Media Services?

Scenario: I've got the project in my app with various videos already processed (submitted transform job, processed and published on CDN) by Azure Media Services. I'm using this project as a template project for other projects in my app so I need to clone videos created by Azure Media Services as well. What's the best approach? I've found this documentation for cloning blobs in [v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-copying-existing-blob), however, I haven't found any resources for v3.

Is it safe to clone just generated blobs using Blob Storage API? If so how to create streaming locators/publish cloned blobs to be accessible via CDN?

What I tried: I know I can submit a new transform job for the original video asset and create new blobs using Azure Media Services API, nevertheless, from a performance perspective, I reckon it could be much efficient just to clone assets on the blob layer and then publish them instead of processing them again.

Is there any other way?

Edit: Cloning videos are essential since users can edit/delete videos in their projects, however, template projects mustn't be affected.

Comment: If you find a good way to solve the issue, you can send your answer share with us. ^-^!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Maybe you can read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/manage-asset-concept). You can download/upload asset. So users can edit/delete videos in their own space, and template asset won't be affected.
Azure-Media-Services v3 don't have document about copying existing blob.

**PREVIOUS**

Why you need to clone videos to other project? Your assets have been storaged in azure and publish on CDN. You can read directly, it's just media content. I think clone to other blob or container may cost you a lot.

I have read document about V2 and V3. In V2, it show us how to copy blobs between two AMS accounts, but V3 not. I also read source code about  [Azure-Media-Services-Explorer For V3](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer/releases), it's a good tools for azure-media-services. In this tools, it support to copy asset to another ams account or self.  Pic like below,

1、Copy asset on Azure-Media-Services-Explorer

[image: Copy asset on Azure-Media-Services-Explorer]

2、Choose AMS Account...
[image: Choose AMS Account...]

You can read source code about it if you also want to clone asset. I think it will useful to u.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've updated my question. I was aware of this tool but haven't examined src code yet, thank you for the suggestion. I think I still need the best practice for cloning though.